# Status bar is turning into white when the application is launched

Tags: android, webview

It's my first question on StackOverflow. I am developing a simple application which only has a WebView with a Progress Bar on it. It's all good so far but when my application launched, the status bar where battery status and clock is at is turning into white.

I'm using Android Studio 1.4 and I'm testing the application on my Nexus 5 which has Android 6.0

My minSdkVersion is 19 and targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion is 23

Here is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ProgressBar
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/progressBar" />

<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/android_web_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

style.xml

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

and finally MainActivity class:
package haber.plus.haberplus;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.android_web_view);

        // Her zaman önbelleği yenile.
        mWebView.clearCache(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                mProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Click here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WJBTG4WtultqpQjKJFo2eK2aLLt5EuVGLZsufF2aV9hwysBuYQzPZ5ZsPborCc3KPnUt=s600) for image which describes the problem.

Comment: your styles.xml and MainActtivity class please

Comment: @MradMrad updated the question..

Comment: check your style.xml inside values-v21 folder. There might be this line:
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>

Answer (score 0):

Seems your Progress Bar is overlapping the status bar, even it's hard to see what's happening on your picture.

Your layout should be fine without 
`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, so try without that.

Comment: It happens when I delete progress bar. So I assume the problem is not progress bar here. I also removed other things you just told to me but it didn't work.

Comment: In general you can change the color of your statusbar with assigning a custom theme to your application. Go to res/values/themes.xml and write in something like
`<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00000</item>
    </style>
</resources>`. The `colorPrimaryDark` defines among others also the color of your status bar, here it get's black (#00000). Then you need to set that custom theme to your application: in your AndroidManifest.xml add `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"` to the `<application ... >` tag.